# Cannot install Pylint on Win 7 machine running Python 3.3.1

Tags: windows-7, python-3.x, pylint

setup.py install fails with the following stack trace. Any ideas?

```
C:\Python33\libs\pylint-0.1.2>python setup.py install
running install
running build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 40, in <module>
    scripts = EnsureScripts('bin/pylint'),

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 569, in run
    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 125, in run
    for cmd_name in self.get_sub_commands():

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 324, in get_sub_commands
    if method is None or method(self):

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 141, in has_scripts
    return self.distribution.has_scripts()

  File "C:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 958, in has_scripts
    return self.scripts and len(self.scripts) > 0

   TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()
```

Comment: Pylint is on version 0.28.0. Why don't you install it with pip?

Comment: @Blender - that would be because I can't get pip working on Windows. Maybe I need to go back to Linux...